# display multiple windows using image_view

Tags: image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all,

If there two image topics:
One is `/camera/rgb/image_color`, the other is `/camera/mono/image_mono`

I want to view these two topics in two separate window:
Then, I try:

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color
```

And then open a new terminal and issue:

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/mono/image_mono
```

However the latter one window will cover the first one. What other parameters for `image_view` I should append to the command?

THX~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222709/display-multiple-windows-using-image_view/) by [Milton](https://answers.ros.org/users/21140/milton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-12-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried just dragging the windows by their title bars to other positions? Assuming they aren't maximised, you can then tile as many windows as you may need.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1